# How to make different tpl depending on the name of the hook for module?

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

In some modules I want to make a different output of information depending on the name of the hook. How to write a working condition in the module tpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a smarty variable with that information, eg. in the hook where you will render a tpl you could do this:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('hook_origin', 'your-hook-name');
return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/myTemplate.tpl');
```

Now in your tpl `myTemplate.tpl` you can evaluate the source hook:

```
{if $hook_origin == 'your-hook-name'}
    {* Your code for this hook here *}
{elseif $hook_origin == 'your-other-hook-name'}
    {* Your code for this hook here *}
{else}
    {* Your code for others *}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thank you... But..  There is a solution code only for tpl? I create a theme for addons. As far as I know, can't not edit php, otherwise they will not accept the theme.

Comment: That’s no posible.

Comment: Help me grow me reputation, please. And I help you too. I wish take you pluse, but need 15 points for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the PHP file of a module then you need to override that module in your theme. And deactivate the default module of a Prestashop.
By overriding the module according to your theme, you are having full control over the PHP and template file.